# Outputting values in 2d array not working

Tags: java

I've tried several times but to no avail it's only outputting the first row.  It's a 2D array, and it's supposed to output 4 rows.  It's not showing any errors.  I think the logical error may be from the for loops which contain the output statements.

```
package aitiDay5;

public class WorldCup {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int i=0,j=0;

        String [][] countries = new String [6][];
        countries[0]=new String[4];
        countries[1]=new String[4];
        countries[2]=new String[4];
        countries[3]=new String[4];
        countries[4]=new String[4];
        countries[5]=new String[4];
        countries[6]=new String[4];

        countries[0][0]="Countries ";
        countries[0][1]="Rival ";
        countries[0][2]="Grade ";
        countries[0][3]="Points ";

        countries[1][0]="Ghana";
        countries[1][1]="Germany";
        countries[1][2]="C";
        countries[1][3]="3";

        countries[2][0]="Croatia";
        countries[2][1]="Greece";
        countries[2][2]="B+";
        countries[2][3]="A-";

        countries[3][0]="USA";
        countries[3][1]="Portugal";
        countries[3][2]="B+";
        countries[3][3]="4";

        countries[4][0]="Spain";
        countries[4][1]="Costa Rica";
        countries[4][2]="F+";
        countries[4][3]="-2";

        countries[5][0]="Brazil";
        countries[5][1]="Germany";
        countries[5][2]="Z";
        countries[5][3]="-32";

        countries[6][0]="Argentina";
        countries[6][1]="Holland";
        countries[6][2]="A";
        countries[6][3]="10";

        for ( i=0;i<=countries.length;i++){
            System.out.println("\n");

            for(j=0;j<countries.length;j++){
                System.out.println(countries[i][j]+ " ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code crashes with `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6`. You cannot access `countries[6]` with `String[][] countries = new String[6][];`. It only goes up to 5.

Answer (score 2):

Your first for loop statement should just use the `<` operator, not the `<=` operator.

Your second loop should index into the row to check the length.

```
for (i = 0; i < countries.length; i++){
    System.out.println("\n");
    for(j = 0; j < countries[i].length; j++){
        System.out.println(countries[i][j] + " ");
    }
}
```

Also, since it appears you want 7 rows, you need to change

```
String [][] countries = new String [6][];
```

to

```
String [][] countries = new String [7][];
```

---

*Side Note*: you don't have to have `i` and `j` outside of the for loops.  You can do this:

```
for(int i = 0; ......){ ... }
```

Comment: @Fritz_Playmaker Glad to help, if your question was answered then please mark the answer as accepted.  If your question wasn't answered then please provide further info.  Happy programming!

Answer (score 0):

Your inner for loop statement should be `for(j = 0; j < countries[i].length; j++)`, and your outer for loop should be `for(i = 0; i < countries.length; i++)`.

As it stands you're not fully looping through the second dimension. I'm actually very surprised that you're not seeing an error, because based on your arrays you should have a ton of illegal access exceptions. Java gets really upset when you try to access past the end of an array (example: your inner arrays only contain 4 elements, but your inner for loop iterates until `j=5`, meaning you're accessing the 5th element in a 4-element array)

Answer (score 0):

YOu need to change this line

```
 for(j=0;j<countries.length;j++){
        System.out.println(countries[i][j]+ " ");
```

To this:

```
 for(j=0;j<countries[i].length;j++){
        System.out.println(countries[i][j]+ " ");
```

Otherwise it will just loop on the single array twice

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simple and you are correct, there is a logical error in your nested for loop.

You are running it against the length of the entire array it should be changed to:

```
for(j=0;j<countries[i].length;j++){
        System.out.println(countries[i][j]+ " ");
}
```